# How to send logs from lambda functions to Kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am Trying to send logs to kibana .Steps are below used

1. Created a lambda function
2. Added In elastic search to search logs as created a lambda function in step 1
3. I m getting logs in Cloud watch log group

Finding the solution to send my logs to kibana

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called [Functionbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/functionbeat/current/index.html).

The easiest way to index your Cloudwatch logs into Elasticsearch and visualize them into Kibana.

See how it works [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/functionbeat-serverless-ingestion-for-elasticsearch)

Answer (score -1):

This guide gives step by step solution: [CONFIGURE CLOUDWATCH LOGS AND KIBANA](https://eksworkshop.com/intermediate/230_logging/configurecwl/)

Comment: Link is broken.