# Is there a native way to stream logs from Cloudwatch to an Elastic Cloud index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

Like you can select a loggroup, and then stream this to an `AWS` `ES` trivially easy by selecting the `loggroup` and selecting `Create Elasticsearch Subscription Filter` can you do the same thing but to an `Elasticsearch` domain in `Elastic Cloud`?

I know you can deploy a `logstash` which will collect logs but I would like to maintain a serverless architecture and not have to manage a `logstash` instance, has anyone written there own Lambda function to do this? Or is this not a cost efficient approach?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62448967/4604579 (hint: Functionbeat)

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out.