# AWS ECS Fargate, send logs to multiple destinations (CloudWatch Logs and Elasticsearch)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ecs, firelens

I have some containers deployed in ECS Fargate, that send the logs to Cloudwatch logs. Now, I want to send **also** the logs to a custom Elasticsearch instance (not Amazon Elasticsearch Service). I have read some info about [firelens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_firelens.html), but it is not clear for me if the logs will be sent also to Cloudwatch logs. Also, all the documentation seems to refer to Amazon Elasticsearch Service, not an own Elasticsearch instance. Do you have any recommendation/snippet of how to do that? Additionally, If I wanted to send the logs to a third, or fourth destination, what would be the approach to do this? Of course, in the cheapest possible way, avoiding Firehose or Lambda tricks.

Comment: The easiest way would be to keep logging to Cloudwatch and then leverage Fuctionbeat to stream your Cloudwatch logs to Elasticsearch. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62448967/4604579

Comment: I and searching for a more native/integrated solution, without additional elements like lambda functions, although the solution looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answear because I don't have the reputation points to comment. Anyway, I suggest you review this [AWS Blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-container-log-destinations-fargate/) on custom firelens configuration to send ecs fargate logs to multiple destinations.

First you'll need to build a custom firelens image and make it available on ECR:

```
FROM amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit:stable
ADD logDestinations.conf /logDestinations.conf
```

The custom image should have a .conf file with your log destinations... Here's an example:

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name                cloudwatch
    Match               YourContainerName*
    region              us-east-1
    log_group_name      app-container
    log_stream_prefix   fluent-bit
    auto_create_group   true
[OUTPUT]
    Name              datadog
    Match             *
    Host              http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com
    TLS               on
    compress          gzip
    apikey            <DATADOG_API_KEY>
    dd_service        <APPLICATION_SERVICE>
    dd_source         <SOURCE>
    dd_message_key    log
    dd_tags           env:dev,<TAG_KEY>:<TAG_VALUE>
```

You will add Firelens as a new container in your TaskDefinition:

```yaml
ContainerDefinitions:
... [Other Containers in your task. E.g.: Your application, datadog agent, etc]
- Name: log-router
  Essential: true
  Image: amazon/customImage:latest
  Cpu: 100
  Memory: 256
  FirelensConfiguration:
    Type: fluentbit
    Options:
      enable-ecs-log-metadata: true
      config-file-type: file
      config-file-value: "/logDestinations.conf"
```

I tested this configuration, it works well. The only thing I had to worry was setting up my image in a separate pipeline, since it's not possible to get the logDestinations.conf file from S3 when using ECS on Fargate.

**Reference:**
https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-container-log-destinations-fargate/